# How to setup CI/CD for nativescript using Visual studio online/Azure dev ops tools

Tags: nativescript, nativescript-angular

Im try so setup a CI/CD Pipeline for a Nativescript app, added the commands to install node and npm install but nativescript has dependencies that it need. How do I go about on Azure dev ops dynamically without having to create a vm that has nativescript and all its dependencies installed and setup

So i have used a VM and install nativescript on it and used and agent to connect to the machine and build solution, i have done the same using jenkins but jenkins was running on the vm, no i want to move the whole pipeline on azure dev ops

command used in build step: tns build android

Answer (score 3):

If you don't want to use a vm you'll have to install everything needed for nativescript before building it on their hosted agent each time you create a build for your app.

A couple of important things to note. First the name of your repository is changed to 's' this messes with the naming of your entitlement file... or at least it did for me. I fix this with a bash file I add to my repository that changes the name of the path in build.xcconfig for the CODE_SIGN_ENTITLEMENTS variable. I added an npm run entitle command in my package.json file to run this before building. Second you'll want to store all files and secure passwords in the library section under pipelines in you Azure Devops project. Third, Using the classic editor is your best friend for figuring out yaml as most jobs have an option to view the YAML. You can also use the classic editor as an alternative to the YAML file

The YAML and bash file below show an example of how you can build an ipa and apk file that is stored as an artifact. You can then use that trigger a release pipeline to push the the play and app store.

```
# YAML File
name: Release Build
trigger:
- release/* # will start build for pull request into release branch ie. realease/version_1_0_0, release/version_2_0_0

pool:
  vmImage: 'macOS-10.13'

variables:
  scheme: 's'   # default name/scheme created on this machine for ipa
  sdk: 'iphoneos'
  configuration: 'Release'


steps:
- task: NodeTool@0
  inputs:
    versionSpec: '10.14'
  displayName: 'Install Node.js'

# Download Secure File for Android
# Note: if multiple secure files are downloaded... variable name will change and break pipeline
- task: DownloadSecureFile@1
  displayName: 'download android keystore file'
  inputs:
    secureFile: myKeystore.keystore

#Install Apple Certificate(Distrobution)
- task: InstallAppleCertificate@2
  displayName: 'Install an Apple certificate Distribution (yourcertificate.p12)'
  inputs:
    certSecureFile: '00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000' # got id from viewing file in clasic editor for pipeline
    certPwd: '$(myCertificatePasswordP12)' # password stored in Library

# Install Apple Provisioning Profile(Distrobution)
- task: InstallAppleProvisioningProfile@1
  displayName: 'Apple Provisioning Profile(myProvisioningProfile.mobileprovision)'
  inputs:
    provisioningProfileLocation: 'secureFiles' # Options: secureFiles, sourceRepository
    provProfileSecureFile: '00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000' # Required when provisioningProfileLocation == SecureFiles

# General Set Up
- script: |
    npm install -g nativescript@latest
    npm install
  displayName: 'Install native script and node Modules'

# variable explination
# $DOWNLOADSECUREFILE_SECUREFILEPATH is keystore file downloaded earlier
# $KEYSTORE_PASSWORD refers to the environment variable in this script which references library variable
# $(MyPlayStoreAlias) refers to library variable for your apps alias
# $BUILD_SOURCESDIRECTORY location where apk is built to

# Android
- script: |
    tns build android --env.production --release --key-store-path $DOWNLOADSECUREFILE_SECUREFILEPATH --key-store-password $KEYSTORE_PASSWORD --key-store-alias $(MyPlayStoreAlias) --key-store-alias-password $KEYSTORE_PASSWORD --bundle --copy-to $BUILD_SOURCESDIRECTORY   #creates apk
  displayName: 'Build Android Release apk'
  env:
    KEYSTORE_PASSWORD: $(MyPlayStoreKeystore)

# create apk artifact
- task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1
  inputs:
    pathtoPublish: '$(Build.SourcesDirectory)/app-release.apk' 
    artifactName: 'apkDrop'
  displayName: 'Publishing apkDrop artifact'

# have to use xcode 10.1 to meet min standards for uploading ipa... default version for this machine was lower than 10.1
#changing xcode version
- script: |
    xcodebuild -version
    /bin/bash -c "echo '##vso[task.setvariable variable=MD_APPLE_SDK_ROOT;]'/Applications/Xcode_10.1.app;sudo xcode-select --switch /Applications/Xcode_10.1.app/Contents/Developer"
    xcodebuild -version
  displayName: 'changing xcode to 10.1'

# Optional... was running into build issues with latest version
#downgrading cocoapods version
- script: |
    sudo gem uninstall cocoapods
    sudo gem install cocoapods -v 1.5.3
  displayName: 'Using cocoapods version 1.5.3'

#iOS
- script: |
    xcodebuild -version # makeing sure the correct xcode version is being used
    pip install --ignore-installed six  # fixes pip 6 error
    npm run entitle #custom bash script used to change entitlement file
    tns run ios --provision     #see what provisioning profile and certificate are installed... helpful for debugging
    tns build ios --env.production --release --bundle    #creates xcworkspace
  displayName: 'Build ios Release xcworkspace'

#build and sign ipa
- task: Xcode@5
  displayName: 'Xcode sign and build'
  inputs:
    sdk: '$(sdk)'   # custom var
    scheme: '$(scheme)' # must be provided if setting manual path to xcworkspace
    configuration: '$(configuration)'   # custom var
    xcodeVersion: 'specifyPath'
    xcodeDeveloperDir: '/Applications/Xcode_10.1.app' #using xcode 10.1
    xcWorkspacePath: 'platforms/ios/s.xcworkspace'
    exportPath: '$(agent.buildDirectory)/output/$(sdk)/$(configuration)'    #location where ipa file will be stored
    packageApp: true    #create ipa
    signingOption: manual
    signingIdentity: '$(APPLE_CERTIFICATE_SIGNING_IDENTITY)' # distribution certificate
    provisioningProfileUuid: '$(APPLE_PROV_PROFILE_UUID)' # distribution profile

#creating ipa artifact
- task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1
  displayName: 'Publishing ipaDrop artifact'
  inputs:
    pathtoPublish: '$(agent.buildDirectory)/output/$(sdk)/$(configuration)/s.ipa'
    artifactName: 'ipaDrop'
```

Bash file

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
# filename: pipeline-entitlements.sh
echo "Editing build.xcconfig"
TARGET_KEY="CODE_SIGN_ENTITLEMENTS"
REPLACEMENT_VALUE="s\/Resources\/YOURENTITLEMENTFILENAME.entitlements"
CONFIG_FILE="./app/App_Resources/iOS/build.xcconfig"
echo "Editing $TARGET_KEY and replaceing value with $REPLACEMENT_VALUE"
sed -i.bak "s/\($TARGET_KEY *= *\).*/\1$REPLACEMENT_VALUE/" $CONFIG_FILE
echo "Finished editing build.xcconfig"
```

Comment: My issue is sudo doesn't work on the pipeline if you letting azure dynamically create the VM on there side so some components cannot be installed and i want the whole build pipeline to sit on azure dev ops

Comment: Interesting... I use sudo (as seen in the YAML example above) on their dynamically created VMs and haven't experienced any issues... does it give you any errors? What components can't you install? By sit on azure dev ops do you mean not using a YAML file that sits in your repo but rather their classic editor that you can edit online through the azure dev ops site or am I way off on what you mean? Just trying to get a better understanding of whats holding you back.

Comment: Im currently using the classic way of building the pipeline not using yaml. The below is an example of the error. The nativescript link below shows components needed for a successful build. I have on my dev machine and believe dont exist on the build VM.  Verify that your environment is configured according to the system requirements described at http://docs.nativescript.org/setup/ns-cli-setup/ns-setup-linux.html#system-requirements.
2019-04-25T09:06:15.9570473Z ##[error]Bash exited with code '127'.
2019-04-25T09:06:15.9582276Z ##[section]Finishing: Build debug APK

Comment: So that setup is for linux. Not sure if thats intentional or not but in order to build an iOS app you'll need to be running their macOS VM which is what my example is using. If you're only building android you can get away with a linux vm but I never tried as I wanted to build for both iOS and android. If you try switching to macOs I bet you'll have better luck. Here is the link for setup on mac https://docs.nativescript.org/start/ns-setup-os-x. Is there a specific reason for linux?

Comment: I am currently only building for Android that is why I used Linux.

Comment: I used the mac0S vm and everything works fine, Linux vm is the issue

Comment: Glad to hear macOS vm is working for you! Just found this issue that may help explain why Linux vm isn't working https://github.com/Microsoft/azure-pipelines-agent/issues/2043

Comment: On this link you can see that the vm can have passwordless sudo for linux, I recently used to install all the dependencies but the problem I had was the android sdk, it seemed liked it couldnt be seen properly and having to download an install it in every build look to much even though there is one installed already https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/hosted?view=azure-devops

Comment: @KBrown do you know if it is possible to split theses tasks into different jobs or even stages?

Comment: @NinjaOnSafari I'm not sure. I would imagine it depends if another hosted agent is used for jobs or stages as most of these tasks depend on each other like the installation of nativescript and the files downloaded for signing. I would test it out. My guess would be it could be possible as long as it uses the same vm, but definitely wouldn't work if you tried to run them in parallel jobs/stages. Is there any specific reason for using different jobs or stages or is just for better organization?

Comment: For anyone interested, there's a simple "fix" so you don't have to have your app (and subsequent built files) renamed to 's'.  Nativescript uses the project's folder name as the name of the application.  When you use the defaults in Azure DevOps for checking out your repository, it puts it into the 's' directory by default.  You can override this by adding a checkout step and specifying the path:  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/yaml-schema?view=azure-devops&tabs=schema#checkout